# How to combine the Bevel shader with displacement and bump textures

Tags: texturing, shaders, baking

Edit: the displacement node has been changed in more recent builds, before it was used as a bump effect, now it displaces the geometry by default so you can't reproduce my issue in this post.

I want to combine the new bevel shader with a displacement/bump texture but when I use it the bevel the details are smoothed and becomes invisible:

[image]

How can I combine the noise displacement with the bevel shader?

Comment: I have removed this sentence, apparently since the latest build the displacement socket displaces the geometry to use it with adaptative subsurf, in the 2.79 it's used as a bump map by default. So his solution of converting it into an height map and using it in the normal input of the bevel works, I mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Bump node to convert the texture into the required Normal to feed into the Bevel node - rather than using the Displacement socket :

[image: Nodes]

The Bump node takes the height information and generates a Normal and the Bevel node can use this Normal instead of overriding the one generated by the Displacement.

Comment: Hi, I have tested with the latest build my node setup and my issue has been fixed, I can see the displacement when I plug it on the displacement socket. I had reported the bug several month ago saying that the bevel should be applied before the displacement and not after and apparently they changed that so it occurs before. My displacement is not smoothed anymore and I can add scratches and noise. So this question is useless now, thanks for trying to help me. I should have tested before featuring it.

Comment: Cool - glad it’s resolved. I guess that’s one problem of using the latest features!

Comment: Finally your solution works because they have changed the behavior of the displacement in the latest build it can't be used like a bump map but it displaces the model. It's maybe to allow to use adaptative subsurf and micro-polygon displacement more easily. You should post a non-blurred node setup, you can use my image if you want: http://i.imgur.com/9i4TeAY.png